# Customized hour and minutes values inside android Digital timepicker

Tags: android, customization, android-timepicker

In my app, the user have to choose appointment time using timpepicker But i have to show only available time in the time picker . So far i have customized the timePicker class by extending parent class and maximum and minimum time has been set using function.

Main problem is that unwanted time has been disabled properly by customizing. But i just don't want to show time at which appointment is not available i.e. not showing disabled time.

This is my customized code.

```
public class RangeTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    private int minHour = -1;
    private int minMinute = -1;

    private int maxHour = 25;
    private int maxMinute = 25;

    private int currentHour = 0;
    private int currentMinute = 0;

    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private DateFormat dateFormat;


    public RangeTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
        currentHour = hourOfDay;
        currentMinute = minute;
        dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

        try {
            Class<?> superclass = getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field mTimePickerField = superclass.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker");
            mTimePickerField.setAccessible(true);
            TimePicker mTimePicker = (TimePicker) mTimePickerField.get(this);
            mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }

        fixSpinner(context, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
    }

    public void setMin(int hour, int minute) {
        minHour = hour;
        minMinute = minute;
    }

    public void setMax(int hour, int minute) {
        maxHour = hour;
        maxMinute = minute;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        boolean validTime = true;
        if (hourOfDay < minHour || (hourOfDay == minHour && minute < minMinute)){
            validTime = false;
        }

        if (hourOfDay  > maxHour || (hourOfDay == maxHour && minute > maxMinute)){
            validTime = false;
        }

        if (validTime) {
            currentHour = hourOfDay;
            currentMinute = minute;
        }

        updateTime(currentHour, currentMinute);
        updateDialogTitle(view, currentHour, currentMinute);
    }

    private void updateDialogTitle(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        String title = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        setTitle(title);
    }


    private void fixSpinner(Context context, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // android:timePickerMode spinner and clock began in Lollipop
            try {
                // Get the theme's android:timePickerMode
                final int MODE_SPINNER = 2;
                Class<?> styleableClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$styleable");
                Field timePickerStyleableField = styleableClass.getField("TimePicker");
                int[] timePickerStyleable = (int[]) timePickerStyleableField.get(null);
                final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null, timePickerStyleable, android.R.attr.timePickerStyle, 0);
                Field timePickerModeStyleableField = styleableClass.getField("TimePicker_timePickerMode");
                int timePickerModeStyleable = timePickerModeStyleableField.getInt(null);
                final int mode = a.getInt(timePickerModeStyleable, MODE_SPINNER);
                a.recycle();
                if (mode == MODE_SPINNER) {
                    TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findField(TimePickerDialog.class, TimePicker.class, "mTimePicker").get(this);
                    Class<?> delegateClass = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePicker$TimePickerDelegate");
                    Field delegateField = findField(TimePicker.class, delegateClass, "mDelegate");
                    Object delegate = delegateField.get(timePicker);
                    Class<?> spinnerDelegateClass;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        spinnerDelegateClass = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate");
                    } else {
                        // TimePickerSpinnerDelegate was initially misnamed TimePickerClockDelegate in API 21!
                        spinnerDelegateClass = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePickerClockDelegate");
                    }
                    // In 7.0 Nougat for some reason the timePickerMode is ignored and the delegate is TimePickerClockDelegate
                    if (delegate.getClass() != spinnerDelegateClass) {
                        delegateField.set(timePicker, null); // throw out the TimePickerClockDelegate!
                        timePicker.removeAllViews(); // remove the TimePickerClockDelegate views
                        Constructor spinnerDelegateConstructor = spinnerDelegateClass.getConstructor(TimePicker.class, Context.class, AttributeSet.class, int.class, int.class);
                        spinnerDelegateConstructor.setAccessible(true);
                        // Instantiate a TimePickerSpinnerDelegate
                        delegate = spinnerDelegateConstructor.newInstance(timePicker, context, null, android.R.attr.timePickerStyle, 0);
                        delegateField.set(timePicker, delegate); // set the TimePicker.mDelegate to the spinner delegate
                        // Set up the TimePicker again, with the TimePickerSpinnerDelegate
                        timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
                        timePicker.setCurrentHour(hourOfDay);
                        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
                        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
                        timePicker.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Field findField(Class objectClass, Class fieldClass, String expectedName) {
        try {
            Field field = objectClass.getDeclaredField(expectedName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {} // ignore
        // search for it if it wasn't found under the expected ivar name
        for (Field searchField : objectClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (searchField.getType() == fieldClass) {
                searchField.setAccessible(true);

                return searchField;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when i was working on custom date picker dialog.

I would suggest you to fork and use [date time picker library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) because these are highly customizable library. And change its layouts as you want.

Comment: Hey , thanks for your response . One thing i wanted to ask that how can we change theme to spinner mode in this library

Comment: date or time or year, what you want in spinner mode?

Comment: I want Time in spinner mode , i have added screenshot. Like that.

Comment: Where is screenshot

Comment: Sorry for delay, an error occurred while i was uploading screenshot,Now check please

Comment: Dude i suggest you use latest date picker library, the screenshot you added contains very old UI (kitkat) of time picker. Best thing to use date picker library is that it looks same in all versions of mobile (default does not). and it is highly customizable as your app theme.

Comment: Actually its a digital time picker and requirement of the client that's why i asked.

Comment: Then you should search for a picker library, that matches some of your requirement then fork it, then change it as your requirement. I will suggest you finish your project first with default date picker. and then after finishing project implement this, because these things consume time.